# Phalcon PHP Xampp installation - Apache can't find DLL

Tags: php, apache, xampp, wamp, phalcon

I am using Windows 7 64bit, Xampp 1.8.3(with PHP 5.5). I'am following [Phalcon installation guide](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/xampp.html), i downloaded x86 version of Phalcon like in this guide. Next i put php_phalcon.dll file in D:/xampp/php/ext. Then, i add to php.ini file:

```
extension=php_phalcon.dll
```

Great, so i lunch Xampp and start Appache. And then:

[firest error http://ubplanet.pl/uploads/images/UBPlanet-1392741295-U15373.png](http://ubplanet.pl/uploads/images/UBPlanet-1392741295-U15373.png)

After click OK, I instantly get second error:
[second error http://ubplanet.pl/uploads/images/UBPlanet-1392741373-U15373.png](http://ubplanet.pl/uploads/images/UBPlanet-1392741373-U15373.png)

Well, i tried everything: reinstalling xampp; install it on C drive; So i try to install phalcon on WAMP, but i also got error like this! So I decide to reinstall whole Windows, with disk formatting. And on the brand new Windows, i also have the same errors. It looks like PHP can't load libraries, but why?

Comment: If you are using 64-bit Xampp (it's not clear from your description) you can simply not run any 32-bit PHP extension. Furthermore, you talk about *the* x86 version but I can count 6 x86 versions in the [download section](http://phalconphp.com/en/download/windows). I suspect you're just trying to run the first DLL you found.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you are using Xampp x64 it does not mean your php is x64

first your need to check your setup from phpinfo you need to check 3 things

- php version
- Compiler
- Architecture

in case, you have Architecture x84 and Compiler VC11 you need to download the dll that met your setup from phalcon site

about the version the latest version supported in the current time of writing this answer on phalcon site is 5.5.0

if your php version is higher like 5.5.5 you need to search for custom build for Phalcon
you can check this one on github https://github.com/andont/phalcon-win
this one had worked with me personally.

if all of this does not work and you could not find any dll mach you setup ( and I believe you can find one) in this case you have to build your own by compiling the source code on Microsoft visual studio that met your setup compiler and architecture and I hope you don't end up with the last solution :)

Comment: This is the answer. PHP version was a problem in my case as well. I  hope that Phalcon team will catch up with latest php release soon so this custom build won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Wow, it saved me! I just got the latest Windows XAMPP bundle which comes with PHP 5.5.15 and had the same problem. After downloading the php_phalcon_5.5.5_TS_x86.dll from Github, Apache started without complains and Phalcon got loaded!
Thanks guys.

Comment: @fernandojmartin did you change name file php_phalcon_5.5.5_TS_x86.dll become php_phalcon.dll

Comment: Sorry Freddy, don't remember. It has been so much time ago.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/tag/v3.4.1) you can find rest of them. Remember, file name is: phalcon_ARCHITECTURE_VC-VERSION_phpVERSION.zip. All the info you can find in phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

I've had so much trouble with PHP and windows, it might behoove you to simply download virtualbox, and spin up an ubuntu virtual machine. You'll have the benefits of running the project in an environment that is likely very similar, if not almost identical to the environment that you'd be running if it were ever on a production server.  This doesn't expressly answer your question, I know, but it's just good advice.